# Searching for novel about space exploration

Tags: story-identification, novel

The novel opens as a young boy is awakened by his father and scientist colleagues to witness images from one of the Voyager (?) probes. He is given a tub of ice cream to reinforce the significance of the occasion. As a scientist in later in life, he is part of the "Grand Tour" mission to explore the Solar System. I think there is a parallel narrative about America becoming a restrictive state. They have developed a Star Wars-type defence system called "Battlestar America". At least I think it’s the same book--it’s been a while. Read in the 80s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Norman Spinrad's *[Russian Spring](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/633188.Russian_Spring)* seems to match.

[image: Front cover of Russian Spring]

> In the near future, the debt-laden U.S. owns a technology that renders it "the world's best-defended Third World country." The only real outer-space planning is in Common Europe, so young American "space cadet" Jerry Reed goes to work in Paris. He falls in love with and marries Soviet career bureaucrat Sonya Gagarin and the story jumps ahead 20 years, blending world events with a focus on their family. Sonya's star has risen with the Euro-Russians' while Jerry has been stymied by pervasive anti-Americanism. Daughter Franja has her father's space fever and enrolls in a Russian space school; son Bob, fiercely curious about an earlier, admired America before it was run by xenophobic "Gringos," enters Berkeley. Ten years later the U.S. is a pariah, Euro-Russia the pet of the civilized world and the Reeds scattered--politics forced Jerry and Sonya's divorce, Franja speaks only to her mother and Bob is trapped in "Festung Amerika." A series of odd, occasionally tragic events brings the family (and the world) together. Despite some tech-talk this is not science fiction: the first two-thirds of this hefty book is chillingly logical, if sometimes very funny, and while the "happy" ending may seem forced, Spinrad (Bug Jack Barron) gives us a wild, exhilarating ride into the next century.

[This review](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/1991/09/26/book-world/dd447ef9-6f69-406c-98ae-5c0259a6c770/) mentions the space defense and the ice cream.

> It is the early 21st century, and the world is divided into three trading blocs. The United States has succumbed to protectionism and militarism. Dominant in its Latin American sphere of influence, it has bankrupted its economy fighting pointless South American wars and building an invincible space-based defense system (which Spinrad slyly names "Battlestar America").

....

> Spinrad's hero, Jerry Reed, is a Californian who lives for space travel. In 1969, when Reed was 4, his father made sure that he would remember the Apollo 11 landing by having him eat chocolate ice cream with chocolate sauce when Neil Armstrong stepped on the moon. But after the Challenger accident destroyed America's civilian space program, Reed is able to find work only on low-level defense projects.

Found with a search for `novel "Battlestar America"`

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178928/book-about-a-man-who-is-a-rocket-engineer-and-ends-up-having-his-brain-removed/178935#178935, which focuses more on the whole brain removal angle.

Comment: Great! Thanks! That's it.